# How to parse for lines with specific format in a file

Tags: c++, parsing, text, token

I recently tried to parse subtitle files to modify the timing on my own. The format is pretty simple, a valid line looks like this:

```
<arbitrary lines might include comments, blanks, random stuff>
<consecutively numbered ID here>
01:23:45,678 --> 01:23:47,910
<arbitrary lines might include comments, blanks, random stuff>
```

How can I do this in an elegant way in C++. I only came up with pretty ugly solutions. For example to read the file line-by-line, search for '-->' in each one and then run over this line with a sequence of find(':'), find(',') and substr()

I feel like there must be a nicer way though, for example by splitting by tokens somehow. It would be ideal if I can still parse lines like:

```
01 : 23    :45,678   -->  01:23:   45, 910
```

correctly. End result should be each part (hh, mm, ss, ms) in a variable. I'm not necessarily asking for a complete implementation. A general idea and references to appropriate utility functions is completely enough.

Comment: Other than reading a lot of data into a buffer and parsing the buffer; reading line by line into a `std::string` is the common and preferred method for parsing text files.

Comment: Your file format is undefined, or you have not (provided) enough information

Comment: Some inspiration [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127889/writing-a-lexer-in-c).

Comment: Ok, seems like there is no easy answer. I was hoping this could be done with the help of a couple of utility IO functions. I like the state machine approach because we did sth very similar at university. The problem with reading each line into a string is that I can't continue parsing it with getline and a custom delimiter like I could with a ifstream. So is there nothing better than a sequence of find, substr and trim?

What exactly is undefined about my file format @DieterLücking ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that with `std::regex`. You define, which tokens to extract and the regex will do that for you. Of course you can modify the input string. It will still work. And you can continue to work with the data in the vector. Rather simple.

See some skeleton code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>

// Our test data (raw string). So, containing also \" and so on
std::string testData(R"#(01 : 23    :45,678   -->  01:23:   45, 910  ?")#");

std::regex re(R"#((\b\d+\b))#");

int main(void)
{
    // Define the variable id as vector of string and use the range constructor to read the test data and tokenize it
    std::vector<std::string> id{ std::sregex_token_iterator(testData.begin(), testData.end(), re, 1), std::sregex_token_iterator() };

    // For debug output. Print complete vector to std::cout
    std::copy(id.begin(), id.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));

    return 0;
}
```